# Is Talos not an aspect of Gruumsh anymore in 5e-era Forgotten Realms?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

I'm setting my campaign in 5e Forgotten Realms and I have a cleric of Talos in my group. While I was dusting off my knowledge of the Forgotten Realms (I skipped the whole spellplague and 4e stuff in the past years) I discovered that in 4e Talos was merged with Gruumsh, being basically his aspect. BUT I cannot find anything about that in 5e, are they back being 2 different entities? The Wiki's are outdated and there seems to not be any info about their merger in the Sword Coast Adventure book, which is afaik the only Forgotten Realm licensed book for 5e.

Any info would be greatly appreciated, Forgotten Realms have always been a mess as far as gods are concerned and this flip-flop between 4e and 5e with spellplague and sundering has only complicated things with gods dying and then coming back to life etc. etc.

I always struggled to follow the chaotic history of the Realms, but it seems that lately things have become (if possible) even worse..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer myself here and say it's up to the DM.

This because it looks like they are indeed treated as 2 different entities in the Sword Coast Adventure Guide, but I guess that a DM can keep the 4e twist if he really liked the fact that they were the same deity with only different aspects.

Things might change when we have more books published, but this is the present situation as far as canon is concerned.

UPDATE: confirmed they are different entities again in 5e -> https://twitter.com/Sernett/status/877036497165139968

Comment: If an update changes the weight of your answer, you should probably make a new answer (even if it's to your own question) and select a new "best answer".